# How to call Dot net webservice with with (x-www-form-urlencoded) format ASMX on Android

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, android-asynctask, http-headers

- How to call Dot net webservice with with (x-www-form-urlencoded)
  format ASMX on Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will be helpful for you

http://androidexample.com/Dot_Net_Webservice_Call_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=100&aaid=122